# Can alternative greens like kale or spinach be used in place of escarole in the Italian Wedding Soup recipe

Tags: soup, italian-cuisine

Can alternative greens like kale or spinach be used in place of escarole in [this Italian Wedding Soup recipe](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/13024/italian-wedding-soup-i/), and if so, how might this change the flavor of the soup?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  We don't answer questions about nutrition here, so I've removed that part of your question.

Comment: If you can find it, I would prefer the flat-leafed lacinato kale (aka Tuscan kale or cavolo nero) to the curly-leaf varieties. In soups, I find curly-leaf kale can be bulky and stringy, while flat-leaved kale has a much more appealing texture.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can easily substitute for it.  I'd take the kale over the spinach, because you want a green that has some tooth to it after boiling.  For the kale, you'll need to remove the thick parts of the stems because they won't cook in time.  Swiss chard would be an even better substitution, and would allow you to use the stems.

No changes to the rest of the recipe are necessary.